# +1 to a field when an image is click in Domino Designer - Formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have an image in Domino Designer on a form, I want to + 1 to a field elsewhere on the same form when the image is clicked. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, it look like a course exercice...

1. Add a field name *plusOne* (or what ever) type number, computed, value:

   ```
   @If(@Text(@ThisValue)="" ; 0 ; @ThisValue)
   ```
2. Select the picture and add an action hotspot
3. Formula for this hotspot:

   ```
   @If(@IsDocBeingEdited ; "life is easy ;-)" ; @Command([EditDocument]) );
   FIELD PlusOne:=PlusOne+1
   ```

Comment: make the field Editable or Computed when composed, otherwise it will reset to 0 every time you press F9

Comment: Thanks for your reply! For some reason I can only get this to work with a button? In addition is there a way of doing this without going into actually 'edit' the form itself?

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer This will only work when I use a button? Also can I get this to work without going into 'edit' mode when using the form itself inside the DB?

Comment: You can force the form to be opened in edit mode: set properties of the form (2nd tab) On open: Automatically enable Edit Mode

Answer (score 2):

To add an action without creating a button, right click the image and select 'Add action default'. If you want only part of the image to be clickable, select 'Add action rectangle' (or circle or polygon) and draw the clickable region.

If you need it to work without being in edit mode, you need to use LotusScript instead of formula. (There is the old-fashioned option of having the button run an agent, but that's really not a good idea; it will cause lots of distracting UI flashes).

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
    Dim doc As NotesDocument 
    Set doc = uidoc.Document
    value = doc.GetItemValue("counterField")
    Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("counterField",value(0)+1)
    Call doc.Save(True,False,False)
    Call uidoc.Refresh

End Sub
```

Note that the above applies to Notes client applications only. The LotusScript hotspot won't work in a browser.